# PDO ruining my JSON with &quot;

Tags: php, json, pdo

I'm storing a JSON array in a mysql TEXT field using PDO. (encoded with `json_encode()`)

Once I get the data, if I do json_decode the result is `NULL`.

It seems that PDO is replacing every " with `&quot;`.

I have already use PDO and JSON together multiple times, but this is the first time I got this problem so I don't understand what's happening.

I'm on PHP 5.4.4

Also, the JSON is sent with AJAX for your information

Thanks if you can help.

Example of JSON in the table :

```
{"type_voie":"BD","indice_repetition":"T","num_voie":"121","nom_voie":"NOM_RUE","infos_voie":"NOM_RUE2","distribution_speciale":"BP789","cp":"34000","ville":"MONTPELLIER","bureau_distributeur":""}
```

What i really see with var_dump :

```
{&quot;type_voie&quot;:&quot;BD&quot;,&quot;indice_repetition&quot;:&quot;T&quot;,&quot;num_voie&quot;:&quot;121&quot;,&quot;nom_voie&quot;:&quot;NOM_RUE&quot;,&quot;infos_voie&quot;:&quot;NOM_RUE2&quot;,&quot;distribution_speciale&quot;:&quot;BP789&quot;,&quot;cp&quot;:&quot;34000&quot;,&quot;ville&quot;:&quot;MONTPELLIER&quot;,&quot;bureau_distributeur&quot;:&quot;&quot;}
```

This is inserted with a prepared query

Code for retrieve DATA :

```
        $formDataSQL = '
            SELECT * FROM '.$this->prefix.'
            WHERE formalite_id = '.$this->proc_id.'
        ';
        $formDataReq = self::$db->prepare($formDataSQL);
        $formDataReq->execute();
        $formData = $formDataReq->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

Then on the JSON field :

```
$addrData = json_decode(str_replace('&quot;', '"', $champ['value']), true); // WORKING BUT NOT MAINTAINABLE
$addrData = json_decode($champ['value'], true); // NOT WORKING => NULL + JSON ERROR = JSON_ERROR_SYNTAX
```

Here is a simplified example of my insert code :

```
        foreach($saveData['personne_physique'] as $field => $value){
            if(is_array($value)) $value = json_encode($value);
            $param = ':'.$field;
            $fields .= $field.'='.$param.', ';
            $values[$param] = $value;
        }
        $fields = trim($fields, ', ');

        $persPhysSQL = "UPDATE personne_physique SET $fields WHERE personne_id = ".$this->id;
        $persPhysReq = self::$db->prepare($persPhysSQL);
        $persPhysReq->execute($values);
```

Here is how I'm connecting :

```
    $host = 'mysql:dbname='.BDD_NAME.';host='.BDD_HOST.';charset=utf8';
    $user = BDD_USER;
    $pass = BDD_PASS;
    $db = new PDO($host, $user, $pass, array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES utf8") );
```

This is really strange :(

Comment: Try and use trim() on your result. and then json decode it. or use htmlspecialentitys().

Comment: Not working. I'm sure that the problem comes from "&quot", because if I replace them it works. But I want to fix this problem, not make a replace everytime.

Comment: Could you post some code?

Comment: Yes, but it's just a simple json_encode with a PDO prepared query, I don't think this will be helpful

Comment: Please post your piece of code where you retrieve your json form the database.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my example script based on your data example:

```
<?php
try {
        $Connection = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=testing', USER, PASS);
        $Connection->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
}catch(PDOException $e){
        echo 'Unable to connect to database' . "\n";
}

$id = $argv[1];

try {
        $data = $Connection->prepare('SELECT * FROM `stackoverflow_26399231` WHERE ID = :id');
        $data->bindParam(':id', $id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $data->execute();
        while($row = $data->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)){
                print_r($row);
                print_r(json_decode($row->data));
        }
        $Connection = null;
}catch(PDOException $e){
        echo 'Error executing query: ' . $e->getMessage() . "\n";
}
?>
```

The database table looks like this:

```
*************************** 1. row ***************************
  id: 1
data: {"type_voie":"BD","indice_repetition":"T","num_voie":"121","nom_voie":"NOM_RUE","infos_voie":"NOM_RUE2","distribution_speciale":"BP789","cp":"34000","ville":"MONTPELLIER","bureau_distributeur":""}
```

When you run the script in the CLI, you get this back:

```
stdClass Object (
    [id] => 1
    [data] => {"type_voie":"BD","indice_repetition":"T","num_voie":"121","nom_voie":"NOM_RUE","infos_voie":"NOM_RUE2","distribution_speciale":"BP789","cp":"34000","ville":"MONTPELLIER","bureau_distributeur":""}
)

stdClass Object (
    [type_voie] => BD
    [indice_repetition] => T
    [num_voie] => 121
    [nom_voie] => NOM_RUE
    [infos_voie] => NOM_RUE2
    [distribution_speciale] => BP789
    [cp] => 34000
    [ville] => MONTPELLIER
    [bureau_distributeur] =>
)
```

How does my script differ to yours?  I'm not able to reproduce the issue.

**UPDATE:**

My update script following your example:

```
try {
        $Connection = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=testing', USER, PASS);
        $Connection->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
}catch(PDOException $e){
        echo 'Unable to connect to database' . "\n";
}

$id = $argv[1];

$ary = array(
        'foo' => 'bar',
        'bar' => 'foo',
        'a' => 'b',
        'c' => 'd',
        'e' => 'f'
);

try {
        $fields = 'data=:data';
        $values = array('data' => json_encode($ary));
        $update = $Connection->prepare("UPDATE `stackoverflow_26399231` SET $fields WHERE ID = $id");
        $update->execute($values);
        $Connection = null;
}catch(PDOException $e){
        echo 'Error executing query: ' . $e->getMessage() . "\n";
}
```

Using the same script to receive as above but changing from PDO::FETCH_OBJ to PDO::FETCH_ASSOC as that's what you're using, I get this output:

```
Array
(
    [id] => 1
    [data] => {"foo":"bar","bar":"foo","a":"b","c":"d","e":"f"}
)

stdClass Object
(
    [foo] => bar
    [bar] => foo
    [a] => b
    [c] => d
    [e] => f
)
```

So I can still not reproduce the issue you're having.  There must be something different between the two scripts.

Comment: I see no differences... I think the quotes are replaced on the insert. This is really strange... Maybe it's because of the prepared statement

Comment: I see no differences... Maybe the connection ? (see edited post)

Comment: I changed my connection to have charset=utf8 and also added the array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES utf8") when initiating the PDO but I'm still not seeing the same issue.

Comment: I give up, this is really frustrating. I will use a custom json_decode function everywhere. 
Thanks a lot for your time

Comment: Have you tried running a test script against your database using my example scripts?  Does that work?